# OpenShift Online v3+ - Adding new route gives forbidden error

Tags: routes, openshift, redhat

I successfully installed on OpenShift Online (Starter Plan, US Virginia server) a Java Web Application (with MySQL Persistent service). The runtime is Tomcat. I managed to build the WAR from an external Git repository (via ssh authentication moreover) and deploy the app to the container. It is reachable from autogenerated route, but i'm getting a weird error setting up a custom new one linked to a www domain. Here's the message:

Route is invalid: spec.host: Forbidden: you do not have permission to set the host field of the route.

I suppose that's a platform bug, but don't know how to work it out (if possible). Any idea please? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is meant by *Supports Custom Domains* for the non-starter (Pro) plan.  With the starter plan, you cannot specify domain names.

Comment: Correct, Starter plans cannot have custom domains.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean that i'm not able to set a public hostname as route to my app (eg. www.mydomain.com) anymore. If you're right, means that the policy has recently changed, because it used to work untill few days ago with the starter plan.

Comment: This has *always* been the [policy](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html). I believe there was a grace period during the initial launch of Starter where this may not have been enforced. However, you *can* create a public hostname. By leaving the `host` value blank when creating a route, you will automatically have a public URL generated.

Comment: That would explain why my route does not work anymore. Since sometime I get the same issue when i try to upload via shell the sqldumpdir, i thought there were temporary problems on the platform.. thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

I get same error messages on OKD 4.

> Forbidden: you do not have permission to set host fields in ingress rules

The root cause was ingresses managed by routes and routes needing extra ClusterRole settings to update those fields.

[Allow route spec.host to be controlled by permission](https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/13905/files#diff-3c0af311c14a25f4f5d3f1b5ec19980cR90-R97) merged at 2017/3

So we need to add extra permissions to the Service Account who want to update ingresses

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: foobar-openshift-ingress
rules:
- apiGroups: ["route.openshift.io"]
  resources: ["routes", "routes/custom-host"]
  verbs:  ["create", "patch"]
```

Binding this ClusterRole to your Service Account, everything will work.

Comment: fyi had this today on IBM Cert Manager (copy of jetstack cert-manager). Your RB role fix worked for me. Thanks.